# Где стажироваться?

Tags: работа

Изучаю веб-программирование на локальной машине с сервером Apache. (js,php).
Но литература более теоретическая нежели практическая. Подскажите, где можно постажироваться, пусть даже бесплатно. А то получается - знаешь дофига теории, а просматриваешь готовые сайты - офигеваешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если "пусть даже бесплатно" то выберите для себя какой-нибудь понравившийся сайт. За примером далеко ходить не нужно. Вот сайт hashcode.ru например. Возьмите и напишите аналог. Можно без каких либо функций. Например без рейтинга или без дизайна вообще. Зависит от того, что вы хотите прокачать. Если хотите прокачать php то не заморачивайтесь над красотой. Напишите просто функции/классы/методы, которые Вам нравятся на этом сайте. Сделайте обычный вывод на страницу с помощью echo/print и всё.

Затем вы возможно захотите прокачать дизайнерские навыки или может быть навыки верстки. Пожалуйста. У Вас уже будет готов аналог hashcode вот на нем и практикуйтесь.

Не нравится hashcode.ru найдите то, что Вам понравится. Либо если Вам кажется, что это сложно то найдите, что-то попроще.

А потом можно и на фриланс податься. Брать простые задачки на php. У Вас уже будет небольшой опыт. Там тоже можно попрактиковаться. Причем еще и денежку срубить за это :)